# Round robin to select elements of list

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list like below

**list1 = [cont1,cont2,cont4,cont5]**

how do i implement round robin logic in python to select elements of a list, 
each time i try to access element

Answer (score 22):

I'd suggest using [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).

> Make an iterator returning elements from the iterable and saving a
>   copy of each. When the iterable is exhausted, return elements from the
>   saved copy. Repeats indefinitely.

Sample usage:

```
seq = [1,2,3,4]
round_robin = itertools.cycle(seq)

assert round_robin.next() == 1
assert round_robin.next() == 2
assert round_robin.next() == 3
assert round_robin.next() == 4
assert round_robin.next() == 1
assert round_robin.next() == 2
assert round_robin.next() == 3
assert round_robin.next() == 4
```

Comment: i think this doesn't works the way i wanted. It is continuously printing result as "1" if i  print round_robin.next().its not iterating over range

Comment: If you recreate generator each time, it'll always start with first value. You need to create `round_robin` once, and call next multiple times on same object. `while True: round_robin = itertools.cycle(seq) print round_robin.next()` won't do.  `round_robin = itertools.cycle(seq) while True: print round_robin.next()` will just fine.

Comment: i want it to be like each time i call this function,it should return me a cycled value(and so also should keep on iterating indefinitely)

Comment: Stateful function? You may pass `itertools.cycle` as a function argument, or create simple class, where instance would hold internal state of round robin logic. Otherwise it does not make much sense, how would you write tests for such function, where behavior differs in each call?

Comment: can you please show a sample example.i will rewrite my requirement-   i need to have say a function which returns a element from list at a time in round robin way ,so that if i call this function in say another function, i should be able fetch returned output and reuse it.

Comment: for python 3 `assert next(round_robin) == 1`

Comment: 'itertools.cycle' object has no attribute 'next'

Answer (score 3):

```
seq = [1,2,3,4]
n = -1
def round_rob_seq():
  global n
  n = n + 1
  return seq[n % len(seq)]

or

def round_rob_seq():
  global n
  n = n + 1
  if n == len(seq):
     n = 0
  return seq[n]
```

Comment: Saving the 'n' n = seq[n % len(seq)] and return n, will prevent it from increasing to infinite and no need for reset code.